# Automate eap to xmi export in Enterprise Architect

Tags: command-line, export, enterprise-architect, xmi

Is there a way to automate the export (conversion) from *.eap to *.xmi in Enterprise Architect? Ideally something like

```
ea -eap file.eap -xmi file.xmi
```

We want to use automated Continuous Integration and clicking through GUI dialogs is not an option. For complex reasons we do not want to check in the xmi in our VCS after the eap file was modified.

The FAQ for XMI export at http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/exporttoxmi.html sadly does not describe an automated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to automate the generation of HTML output in Enterprise Architect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221654/how-to-automate-the-generation-of-html-output-in-enterprise-architect)

Comment: Thanks, xmedeko. My Java-fu is nonexistent and I'm a bit at a loss how to make use of the information at the end of that link. I'm in charge of the build system, not the EA modelling, so my EA knowledge is severely limited (but not my Unix, C, shell, perl, make knowledge). Can you be more specific of what I would have to do? Thanks for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: I am afraid you have to make a program to handle the EA ActiveX Com interface, see [http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/sdk_for_enterprise_architect/theautomationinterface.htm](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/sdk_for_enterprise_architect/theautomationinterface.htm). Maybe you may try to find an ActiveX for Perl or any other language familiar to you.